# How to fix low remote audio in some android devices (Twilio Programmable Video)?

Tags: android, audio, twilio, twilio-video

I have integrated twilio programmable video for video calling between 2 devices, but problem is, in some android devices remote audio is very low. And I have tested other applications like whatsapp, whatsapp audio is loud on those devices.

I have tried audioManager.setMode but it is not working.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_call);

        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

        // Other functionalities
    }
```

Please advise.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Troubleshooting audio guide](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android#troubleshooting-audio) in the Twilio Video Android quick start?

Comment: @philnash, thank you for your replay, I have already tested those configurations, but it didn`t work on some devices, like Tecno CA6, Tecno CA7, Infinix X650, Infinix X609, Nokia 2.2.

But on some devices, audio is loud & clear via loud speaker. like Samsung S9, Samsung Note 8, iPhone X, Samsung Note 9, iPhone 6s.

Please Advise.

Comment: In that case I would recommend [raising this as an issue on the quickstart project](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android/issues) where you will get the attention of the Twilio Video team.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? As im seeing the same issue!

Comment: @nt95 I had tried multiple configurations, but it didn`t work, & I had discussed with the Twilio Team, but they don`t have a solution for that issue.

Comment: @M.AzeemKalhoro I was able to get the audio levels normal! I will post the answer now

Answer (score 3):

I followed the suggest Twilio audio debugging but did not get anywhere, after playing about with what they had suggested I was able to create this function which I call in the onCreate of the activity using Twilio

```
private fun requestAudioFocus() {
    val playbackAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
        .build()
    val focusRequest = AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT)
        .setAudioAttributes(playbackAttributes)
        .setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(true)
        .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener { }
        .build()
    audioManager.requestAudioFocus(focusRequest)
    audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = !isHeadphonesPlugged(this)
}
```

And the check headphone function is

```
 fun isHeadphonesPlugged(context:Context): Boolean {
    val audioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager?
    val audioDevices = audioManager!!.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_ALL)
    for (deviceInfo in audioDevices) {
        if (deviceInfo.type == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADPHONES
            || deviceInfo.type == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I define the audio manager before calling requestFocus()

```
audioManager = this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
```

Hopefully this helps someone!